# How to display alert message box in asp.net core mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to display alert message box when the account model is invalid.
How should i gonna do this in controller in Asp.Net Core MVC?
Here is my Controller's code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(Account model)
    {
        if (model.ID != null && model.PassWord != null)
        {
            using (var db = new AccountDBContext())
            {
                var account = db.Account.FirstOrDefault(
                                a => a.ID.Equals(model.ID) && a.PassWord.Equals(model.PassWord)
                              );

                if(account != null)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");       

            }
            //I want to display error msg box...here like "Check ID or PW".
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");

        }


        return View();
    }
```

I searched the way but there is no "Page" identifier or "Response.write()" Method in this controller class....
How should i gonna do?

p.s
The way that i checked model's validation like that is right way?
(I used a model and check it's partial properties, instead using view model )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the error in your controller:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Check ID");
```

And then display it in the view:

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && ViewData.ModelState["Error"].Errors.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="alert alert-
       <strong>Error!</strong> danger">@ViewData.ModelState["Error"].Errors.First().ErrorMessage
    </div>
}
```

**EDIT**

To show an alert box, add some javascript in your view, the following uses jquery:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && ViewData.ModelState["Error"].Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            <text>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('@ViewData.ModelState["Error"].Errors.First().ErrorMessage');
            });
            </text>
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: OP has asked how to do it using an _alert message box_

Comment: Thanks for answering! but i put below if it is not valid.

<script> alert('@Html.ValidationMessage("Error")')</script>
 Then there is an error occured like this.


<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Error" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

Comment: I fixed a small bug, I just tested it and should do what you want ;)

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot!! (p.s : May i ask ViewData.ModelState["Error"].Errors.Count meaning?)